# How can I programmatically create a Kubeflow recurring run from a pipeline function?

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines, kfp

I am trying to create a recurring kubeflow pipeline run as follows:

```py
from kfp import compiler
compiler.Compiler().compile(
    pipeline_func=my_pipeline,
    package_path='pipelines/my_pipeline.tgz')

from kfp.v2.google.client import AIPlatformClient
api_client = AIPlatformClient(project_id='...',
                             region='...')

api_client.create_schedule_from_job_spec(
    job_spec_path='pipelines/my_pipeline.tgz',
    schedule='* * * * *',
    time_zone='UTC',
    parameter_values=arguments
)
```

The first command creates the pipeline spec in YAML, but the second one expects JSON.

How otherwise can I create the recurring run programmatically [rather than via the UI]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `v1` `kfp.compiler` which indeed produces a yaml output and your API client is `v2`, which indeed expects a json input. Use the `kfp.v2.compiler` to be consistent with the versions, the later saves the pipeline in json, as expected by your `api_client`.

- [Sample v1 hello world produces a yaml](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/master/samples/core/helloworld/hello_world.py)
- [Sample v2 hello world produces a json](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/master/samples/v2/hello_world.py)

You can find an example of creating a v2 pipeline on gcp [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/build-pipeline).